# Informatica Powercenter HTTP Transformation POST Method Upload File

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using Informatica Powercenter 9.6.1. I am trying to upload a file using HTTP Transformation POST method with URL in it. Is that possible? If not using HTTP Transformation, what other ways we can achieve that using INFA PC? Can you please provide me some examples/code to make that possible. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. use a java trans
2. use wput or another commandline tool in a post session script

Based on your (limited) description i would go for option 2 :)